# Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $x \ge 0.$ Find the number of possible values of $f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 10.$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $x \ge 0.$

Find the number of possible values of $f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 10.$

I tried splitting it into cases: $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=2$, ... ,$\lfloor x\rfloor=10$, but I'm not sure how to calculate the number of $f(x)$'s. Could somebody help me here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint. What could be the value of $x \lfloor x \rfloor$, when $\lfloor x \rfloor=n$?

Comment: Forget "number of", have you found any possible values of $f(x)$?

Comment: How many values does $f$ take on $[0,1)$? $[1,2)$?, ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very good hints are in the comments. Please try more before looking at the solution:

> $47$

Working: If you consider $g(x)=x\lfloor x\rfloor$, it is

> piecewise linear as in $g(x)=nx$ if $x \in [n, n+1)$.

So $g(x)$ takes integer values $k$ times where $k = f(x)$.

To further clarify, within $[0, 1), [1, 2), [2, 3), \dots, [9, 10), \{10\}$, $h(x)$ takes the following number of values:

> $1, 1, 2, \ldots, 9, 1.$

Comment: I have one question, why does $g(x)$ take integer values $k$ times where $k=f(x)$? Thanks!

Comment: @Magician since $g$ is increasing and $f = \lfloor g\rfloor$. Try to sketch the graph of $g$ for $x\in [0,3)$ to understand.

Comment: I get it!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Magician you're welcome. Would you consider upvoting and accepting my answer please? Thank you.